# survival package, right censored data

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I account for right censored data in the analysis of my dataset. I am using the `survival` package - given cancer treatment tactics and when the patient last checked in with my clients clinic.

Is there a suggested method or manipulation to the standard `survival` package to account for *right-censored* data?

Our rows are unique individual patients...

Here are our columns that are filled out:

- List item
- our treatment type (constant)
- days since original diagnosis
- 'censored' which is the number of patients who were last heard on this day. Hence, We are          now uncertain if they are still alive or dead seen as they stopped attending the clinic. They should be removed from the probability estimate at all points in future.
- # of patients who died on that day (from original diagnosis)

So do you recommend a manipulation of the standard survival package? Or using another package? I have seen `survSNP`, `survPRESMOOTH` and `survBIVAR` that may perhaps help. I want to avoid recalculations of the individual columns/fields and creating new objects of the R algorithm seeing as this is a small part of a very large dataset.

Comment: This question is not making a lot of sense (yet). The standard application of the functions in pkg survival IS to right-censored data. The data layout needs to be individual level patient rows. Working with an aggregate count of patients-lost-to-followup is not the proper way to analyze the data. I suppose you could construct a univariate survival function with that but you would loose all the capacities of regression on covariates such as sex, age, comorbidity... all the stuff that would be interesting.

Comment: So: post a sample of the patient-level data and resolve the ambiguities and an answer may be forthcoming.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the input. So I think my team had some confusion- we realized that the Survival function calculated the right-censoring data, but we were looking for a solution to remove the right-censored data from the results to render more accurate representation of what was actually happening... Therefore, what I learned from your comment is that you cannot manipulate the survival function or any similar to it, to removed the right-censored population?

Comment: However, we will look to resolve our ambiguities within our data and then share with you. Many thanks for your input!

Comment: The censored patients' data will not affect any of hte calculation to the right of their duarion of observation. That's the whole point of the conditional analysis. They contribute to the riskset (the denominator for the mortality rate calculations) for as long as they each were followed but no longer.